# storeaccountd(453) deny file-write-create when beginning In-App Purchase on Mac

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, appstore-sandbox

Since upgrading to El Capitan, my Mac app which includes an In-App Purchase is failing to process the In-App Purchase. This is the error that I see in the console:

```
storeaccountd(453) deny file-write-create /Users/kenny/Library/Caches/com.inadaydevelopment.mac10biiFinancialCalculator
```

When the user clicks to purchase, they get the App Store login pop-up, and they get the In-App Purchase confirm pop-up with a Buy button. When they click Buy, that Buy confirmation pops up a 2nd time. Then I get the above error message in the console about 15 times. Then I get a final popup that says "An unknown error has occured" with Retry and Cancel buttons.

This app has been working, but once the user upgrades to El Capitan, it horks. What is going wrong?

Here is the full error report from the console:

```
storeaccountd(453) deny file-write-create /Users/kenny/Library/Caches/com.inadaydevelopment.mac10biiFinancialCalculator


Process:         storeaccountd [453]
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeaccountd
Load Address:    0x108432000
Identifier:      storeaccountd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       x86_64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]


Date/Time:       2015-11-17 17:44:11.750 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
Report Version:  8


Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e57c96 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5f2b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5e77c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5dfc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
4   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd9f961 CFRunLoopRun + 97
5   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108439a99
6   libdyld.dylib                 0x00007fff8f8215ad start + 1


Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5e0a2 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff99400d85 _dispatch_autorelease_pool_pop + 0


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e57c96 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5f2b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5e77c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5dfc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
4   CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91efbd6d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
5   Foundation                     0x00007fff92f42ee4 __NSThread__start__ + 1351
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce9b1 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce92e _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc385 thread_start + 13


Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5d78a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5d222 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce9b1 _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce92e _pthread_body + 0
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc385 thread_start + 13


Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e57cd2 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff99409a19 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 594
2   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108436d1a
3   storeaccountd                 0x000000010843c77b
4   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff994068f5 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff9940dbd6 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 1733
7   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993ff253 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993feab8 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce4f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5e1f2 mkdir + 10
1   Foundation                     0x00007fff92f38212 -[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:] + 286
2   StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928c90e9 +[NSFileManager(ISAdditions) ensureDirectoryExists:] + 292
3   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108437d8e
4   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108437ff2
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fc9aa _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
7   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108437677
8   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108437074
9   storeaccountd                 0x0000000108439510
10  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928d4bde -[ISURLOperation _sendOutputToDelegate:] + 101
11  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928d1b5d -[ISURLOperation _handleFinishedLoading] + 937
12  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f21851 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
13  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f21766 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 233
14  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f2166b -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
15  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f26492 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
16  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff920ba977 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
17  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff994090be _dispatch_block_invoke + 474
19  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f21528 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 24
20  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd21e64 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
21  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f21421 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 137
22  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f212c2 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 282
23  CFNetwork                     0x00007fff91f210e4 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
24  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd7f8b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5f0ac __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
26  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5e5cf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
27  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8dd5dfc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
28  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cb771 -[ISOperation runRunLoopUntilStopped] + 46
29  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928d463d -[ISURLOperation _runWithURL:] + 436
30  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928d4410 -[ISURLOperation _run] + 234
31  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928d092e -[ISURLOperation run] + 238
32  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928b73b1 -[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation] + 2707
33  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928b5e37 -[ISStoreURLOperation run] + 354
34  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cc0d5 -[ISOperation _main:] + 426
35  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cbc03 -[ISOperation main] + 547
36  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cb861 -[ISOperation runSubOperation:returningError:] + 209
37  storeaccountd                 0x0000000108438e56
38  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cc0d5 -[ISOperation _main:] + 426
39  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cbc03 -[ISOperation main] + 547
40  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cb861 -[ISOperation runSubOperation:returningError:] + 209
41  StoreFoundation               0x00007fff928cb729 -[ISOperation runSyncReturningError:] + 124
42  storeaccountd                 0x0000000108436e96
43  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
44  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fc9aa _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
45  storeaccountd                 0x0000000108436d1a
46  storeaccountd                 0x000000010843c77b
47  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff994068f5 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
48  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
49  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff9940dbd6 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 1733
50  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993fb3c3 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
51  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993ff253 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
52  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff993feab8 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
53  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951ce4f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
54  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5d78a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5d78a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff87e5d78a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff951cc375 start_wqthread + 13


Binary Images:
       0x108432000 -        0x1084b3ff7  storeaccountd (453.1) <44e44bb6-89e6-3c27-ab8f-c4270e9eb93a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeaccountd
    0x7fff87e46000 -     0x7fff87e64fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (3247.10.11) <fa4dcf42-27b0-3878-9158-e148d208b21e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8dcd5000 -     0x7fff8e14aff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1255.1) <86b26482-c917-34f2-80d8-02911b6001e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8f81e000 -     0x7fff8f821ffb  libdyld.dylib (360.17) <99396189-e53a-3a78-bc49-449236da7cff> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff91ef3000 -     0x7fff9217aff3  com.apple.CFNetwork (760.1.2 - 760.1.2) <d4fd8df6-8481-3be6-9e93-a3268b16774e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff928ab000 -     0x7fff92911ff7  com.apple.StoreFoundation (1.0 - 453.1) <f92b8382-6ef1-3948-aec5-b7d2ef1e4f39> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/StoreFoundation
    0x7fff92f0d000 -     0x7fff93261fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1255.1) <3ad7b198-3943-3919-b6f2-b0c28dc817b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff951cb000 -     0x7fff951d4ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (137.1.1) <1373d0f1-c6ca-364e-a6ba-8bdbd0d34670> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff993f9000 -     0x7fff99426fff  libdispatch.dylib (500.10.1) <438f4595-0731-34a2-acad-60121a76d1ff> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
```

Comment: i am facing a similar issue, did you find the fix for it. Btw are you using MKStoreKit?

Comment: I was testing it with Sandbox account, i was facing the similar problem. Then i completely remove appstore version and then run the non appstore version and it worked for me. Your problem is a bit different but sharing it as anyone lands here or it might give you some pointer to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Mirza, yes, I tried that too. I removed the app store version and rebuilt from Xcode and ran it that way. I still had the same error though. :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution? Thanks

Comment: I am getting same error in Mac app store not in sandbox environment , any workaround to fix it

Comment: As far as I can tell the error message is just a red herring (i.e. it's not the actual problem, it's just a bad log message).

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I was testing with a sandbox user account. The solution was to move the test build and launch it from within the Applications directory rather than the DerivedData hierarchy.